# Trying to reverse a Crompton Parkinson motor

Tags: motor, reverse-polarity

Completely out of my depth here ~ trying to repurpose an old sewing machine motor to turn a flour mill.  Prezzie for the wife who is baking sourdough.[image]

But I need to reverse the direction.

Tried swapping a few wires around but it just kept running the same way.  Hopefully it’s reversible.

From inside the motor there are four wires:

1. Red on its own
2. Green and white sharing a terminal
3. Black on its own

Pictures attached.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

The four terminals are marked as follows:

- top terminal with Red wire:  marked 'Z'
- upper middle terminal with White, Green, red wire: marked 'A-Z'
- lower middle terminal with two Black wires: marked 'A'
- bottom terminal with no wires: marked 'Z'

Also, the wires heading inside the casing have some extra length when pulled out. They're not too taught.

[image]

Comment: Q1. I can see A-Z on one of the terminals. What's on the others? Q2. Is this a "universal" motor with carbon brushes? Q3. Can you figure out which are the winding pairs? Probably green + red and black + yellow. My hunch is that this motor has the field winding in series with the rotor winding and you need to swap the polarity of either one (but not both) to reverse the motor. This is going to be a little awkward since wires are taut. Edit the additional information into your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the post with the terminal markings.  Please let me know which wire to swap around so It reverses.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It’s a 4 pole fan/blower motor. If it’s reversible there is a connection swap to reverse the polarity of one winding so the the magnetic field rotates the other direction. A 5664A is still a common motor. If you can’t find any documentation for your antique you may find some “universal replacement” motors for HVAC repairmen have documentation that includes wire colors found on older types. Having said all that, that motor appears to be old enough to predate nylon magnet wire. If you plan to put it in service change the bearings or the sintered bronze sleeves if it’s a sleeve bearing motor. If you are just going to add grease use a polyurea base electrical motor grease like Mobil Polyrex EM not a lithium base automotive grease or any other machine grease, there’s a substantial difference. I know that can be pricey but it vibration can connect a winding to the frame over time so I suggest using a ground fault interruptor even if you can ground the frame well. The difference is that if it starts to leak current instead of building heat and burning up the windings, it gets shut off so you can have your antique motor’s field re-wound. And for your safety, put a grommet in that cord hole, the threaded hole in the casting will cut through to the insulation on the conductors over time.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try and find some documentation.  Will also put a grommet on that cord - good call!